# Obtener el id de una fila en una tabla desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer que el id del elemento tr se obtenga a través de la función myScript, por medio de JavaScript al seleccionarlo.
[image: Tabla html]

Answer (score -1):

Es muy sencillo si usas jQuery, no solo te va permitir obtener el id de un tr sino de todos los que haya en tu tabla.

Te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#myTable tr', function() {
    var idtr = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(idtr);
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <th>Asientos</th>
  <th>Nombre ocupante</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="select">
  
  <tr id="001">
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Disponible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="002">
    <td>002</td>
    <td>Disponible</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```